# How can I generate a route after doing a calculation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to generate a URL or new route after doing some calculations in Rails 4?

To be more clear let's check this pic:

[image]

After clicking on "calculate" it shows some results but the route is still the same (`localhost:8080/en`). I would like to generate another route, let's say (`localhost:8080/en/outputs/de32r3ff3`) and when I send this route or link to another person, he can see the results just by putting this URL in his browser.

Imagine that `localhost:8080` is `mydomain.com`.

I checked [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for) but it is not clear for me.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: not clear enough. do you post the data to somewhere?

Comment: i think what you really want is just changing the url in the url-bar. this is not rails, its just browser-javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: if i'm wrong, then you need to setup a form and by clicking on "calculate" you need to post the form data to your controller  and by then redirect to your nice path

Comment: I have two controllers: Controller 1 with 2 actions (a and b) and controller 2 with one action. When giving (localhost:8080) starts at 'a'. What you see in the pic (the form). When clicking calculate, it goes to action 'b' then again to the view, then again with AJAX to controller 2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create output controller, and create show action there.

When you are at mydomain.com and see blank form, you need to get form values with JS, and redirect_to `output#show` with these params encoded on button click.

For example:

```
# get params from form and store to params variable in your JS
# let's say you params equal 'kWp=4000&kWh=30'
var encodedParams = btoa('kWp=4000&kWh=30') # a1dwPTQwMDAma1doPTMw
window.location.href = '/output/?' + encodedParams
```

Then you will hit your output#show action on the backend side:

```
def show
  params_string = Base64.decode64(params[:id]) # kWp=4000&kWh=30
  # transform string to hash of params
  params_hash = params_string
                  .split('&')
                  .map {|s| s.split('=')}
                  .inject({}) {|carry, (k, v)| carry[k] = v; carry}
  # now render you form again using params from params_hash
end
```

You can try different encodings to receive shorter url.

So this way you will avoid persisting values to DB, and will calculate your form from decoded params.

EDIT

PS: in this example Base64 encoding is used as you can see from ruby code

Answer (score 0):

**Actions**

> after doing some calculations in Rails 4?

I think you have to look at it from a different perspective; you're not trying to change the route, but send the user to a specific action.

You mention `localhost:8080/en/outputs/de32r3ff3` as the route you wish to send the users to - what's the controller / action you're looking to invoke?

--

The answer lies here:

> he can see the results just by putting this URL in his browser

Thus, what you need is to create a new record for the calculation, which can then be accessed at any time through that particular URL.

This is standard [`CRUD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) behaviour in Rails:

---

**CRUD**

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :en do
   root to: "calculations#new"
   resources :calculations, path: :outputs, only: [:new, :create, :show] #-> url.com/en/outputs/:id
end

#app/controllers/calculations_controller.rb
class CalculationsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :get_calculation, only: :show

   def new
      @calculation = Calculation.new
   end

   def create
      @calculation = Calculation.new calculation_params
      ## user agent stuff you can append as follows:
      #@calculation.user_agent = request.user_agent
   end

   def show
   end

   private

   def get_calculation
      @calculation = Calculation.find params[:id]
   end

   def calculation_params
       params.require(:calculation).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to *save* the calculations in your model:

```
#app/models/calculation.rb
class Calculation < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

--

This will give you the ability to access the `new` view for the `calculations` as the "root" of your `en` namespace:

```
#app/views/calculations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @calculation do |f| %>
   ## your fields here
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

In the end, you'll get a setup which allows you to access:

```
#url.com/en -> calculations/show
#url.com/en/output/:id
```

You'll want to look up using [UUID's in Rails](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/) as well as [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), to achieve